# How can I make the fight between 3 big cat moms believable?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, fantasy

I am rewriting my story about big cat friendship for the greater good. I have taken into consideration the fact that friendships between animals that last are usually friendships that started when the animals are babies or when a mom looses all her babies.

So Duma the cheetah cub is being taken care of by a nomadic lioness. At the same time, Anapumua Moto, the lion cub is playing with Bella, the leopard cub. The leopard mom doesn't mind it yet. But when Duma reaches Anapumua Moto and Bella, all 3 big cat moms(so the cheetah mom, lioness, and the leopard mom) start moving towards the cubs and fighting.

There is only 1 option for all 3 cubs to survive and that is to have Duma lead the way to his nomadic lioness caregiver and have the nomadic lioness take care of all 3 until they are old enough to be independent from her.

The problem I see with this is not with the cubs but rather the moms. I think to make this fight believable, all 3 moms should get fatal injuries or at least injuries painful enough to overpower maternal instincts. That would be easy for the cheetah and the leopard but even if the leopard uses gravity and the cheetah uses speed, both to their advantage, I still can't see how the lioness would become injured enough to not go after Anapumua Moto who is at this point with the nomadic lioness.

Comment: Sorry, this is a "what to write" question, which is off-topic for us, as it is specific to your story and unlikely to help anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

So let the injured lioness go after the cubs and the nomadic lioness.  The wounds which she received from the fight with the other two moms might not be immediately fatal, but they could start her on a slow path to death.
Have her emerge from the fight with a long gash on her flank, curving down into her underbelly. Maybe the panther got in a lucky shot before dying.  Have her lick at the wound but have it keep bleeding.  As she pursues her child, make repeated note of the blood trail she is leaving behind her.  Describe how she is getting weary but let her rage keep her on her feet, ever onward pursuing the cubs.

Meanwhile, milk the scene for tension among the cubs and the nomad.  Use the young lion cub's fear of what its mom is going to do to its new friends to overcome its natural loyalty and love for its mom.  Have the supportive presence of the nomad help as the cub is struggling with mixed loyalties.  Meanwhile, keep all of them running as quickly as possible away from the pursuing danger.

Then, as the cubs are finally cornered and the nomad prepares to lay down its life in defense of the young, have the mother lion finally succumb to her wounds.  Have her collapse and die, perhaps after sharing some last thoughts with her child.  Make it tearful and tragic.  Make your readers cry.

If you do that, your readers may be too busy dealing with their own grief to notice that a couple of significantly outclassed mother cats just took out a lion.